# Can't display content page in state with Angular UI Router

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm beginner in AngularJS and I have a problem when use Angular UI Router.

**index.html**

```
<body ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController" layout="column">
        <ui-view></ui-view>
</body>
```

**login.html**

```
<h1>Login page content</h1>
```

And in my $stateprovider...

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: "/app",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "views/app.html",
        controller: "AppController"
    }).state('app.login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "views/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController"
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
```

It can't display a content of **login.html** page. But when i change state from app.login to login. It can be displayed. How should i do now?

Answer (score 0):

Out of curiosity could you try:

```
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/login');
```

I saw the abstract nested classes routed in that format in some examples, 
though i don't have time to test it in jsfiddle.

edit:

Maybe if you try setting the base url to "/" ?

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider,$locationProvider) {
    $stateProvider
    .state('app', {
        url: "/",
        abstract: true,
        templateUrl: "views/app.html",
        controller: "AppController"
    }).state('app.login', {
        url: "/login",
        templateUrl: "views/login.html",
        controller: "LoginController"
    });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/login');
})
```